# Node reference to show only author of node

Tags: 6, entities, nodes

I have create two content types as Game and Video. For the Video content type, I have created a node reference field that will be referring to the Game type.

Suppose I have 2 users (e.g. user1, and user2) on my site. User1 has created the following nodes:

- Game1 (content type: Game)
- Game2
- Game3

User 2 has created the following nodes:

- Game4
- Game5

Suppose User1 is going to create one Video node. On the node reference selected list, I just want to see Game1, Game2, and Game3, but it is displaying all Games.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Use views integration option in Node Reference Field Settings... You can connect the node reference results with the view results.. When you edit node reference field settings you can see the setting to select view with which Reference Field pulls results...

You need to build a view first that will display all games created by logged in user... Then select this view in node reference field settings....